# How can I group by two variables and create a new variable based on cumsum?

Tags: r, group-by, cumsum

I'm working on a dataset based on hotel reviews. I've created a subset (440880 rows) as follow:

```
 df2
 Hotel_ID  Review_date  Negative_Rev       Positive_Rev   Negative  Positive
        1   2015/08/20     bad staff   comfortable room          1         1
        1   2015/08/30   No Negative         good staff          0         1
        2   2015/09/24      no staff        No Positive          1         1
        2   2016/02/03  No Breakfast   near city centre          1         1
        2   2016/03/22   No Negative        No Positive          0         0
```

where `Negative` and `Positive` are variables based on `Negative_Rev` and `Positive_Rev` (`x = 0 if No Negative or No Positive`).
I would like to group `df2` by `Hotel_ID` and `Review_Date` and create two new columns called `Daily_Negative` and `Daily_Positive` derived from `cumsum` function of respectively `Negative` and `Positive`.
I've tried, for example, with this:

```
> df$Daily_Positive <- ddply(df, .(Review_Date, Hotel_ID), transform, Daily_Positive = cumsum(Positive))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is another soluation using the `data.table` package:

```
library(data.table)
df2[, .(Daily_Negative=sum(Negative), Daily_Positive=sum(Positive)), by=.(Hotel_ID, Review_date)]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
library(dplyr)   
df2 <- df2 %>% group_by(Hotel_ID,Review_date) %>%
               summarise(Daily_Negative = sum(Negative),
                         Daily_Positive = sum(Positive)) %>% 
               ungroup()
```